# Reactjs separation of UI and business logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, separation-of-concerns

I am new to react and I find it sore in the eyes to look at the component flooded with lots of functions and variable initializations together with the UI. Is it possible to separate them?

Instead of the default setup, like below. How do I separate the business logic into another file?

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');
    const someFunc = () => {
        //do something.
    };
    ... some 100-liner initializations

   return ( 
       ...
   )
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what `someFunc` does: Declare it outside the component.

Comment: what I meant by separating them is putting all the business logic inside another js file. @FelixKling

Comment: Make a parent component which should have the business logic, the UI should be in another child component. 
Call the child in the parent passing down all the required props.

Comment: You can do that too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: Take a look at this https://dev.to/mrdulin/react-redux-application-architecture-5f8f

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes it is possible, That is called as `Separation of concern`.

You can create your component structure as below.

```
MyComponentDirectory
 - useCustomHook
 - Component
 - helper
```

The code will look like this one.

**Hook**

```
const useCustomHook = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const handleClick = (value) => {
        setValue(value)
        //do something.
    };
    ... some 100-liner initializations/business logic, states, api calls. 

    return {
        value, 
        handleClick,
        ... // Other exports you need. 
    } 
}

export default useCustomHook;
```

**Component**

```
function MyComponent() {
   const {
       value, 
       handleClick, 
       ... // Other imports 
   } = useCustomHook() 

   return ( 
       <Element value={value} onClick={handleClick} />
   )
}
```

**Helper**

```
const doSomething = () => {}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a detailed example of React counter application using `Separation of concern`

**Structure**

```
Directory
- App
- Counter
- useCounter
- helper
```

**App Component**

```js
import Counter from "./Counter";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Counter Component**

```js
import useCounter from "./useCounter";

const Counter = () => {
  const { count, increaseCount, decreaseCount } = useCounter();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <div>
        <button onClick={increaseCount}>Increase</button>
        <button onClick={decreaseCount}>Decrease</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

**useCounter Hook**

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import numberWithCommas from "./helper";

const useCounter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(9999);

  const increaseCount = () => setCount(count + 1);
  const decreaseCount = () => setCount(count - 1);

  return {
    count: numberWithCommas(count),
    increaseCount,
    decreaseCount
  };
};

export default useCounter;
```

**Helper Function**

```js
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};

export default numberWithCommas;
```

Here's the working example in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-separation-of-concern-3vxv1?file=/src/App.js)

Note: if you create a simple Javascript util function instead of hook then you won't be able to access other hooks, context inside that function.

Comment: I prefer this answer than below since it does not mess up the states.

Comment: Updated the example with Real React counter and working example at Codesandbox.

Comment: This is amazing example! Upon further thinking, we could move `numberWithCommas(..)` method out of custom hook and directly call in ui `<p>{numberWithCommas(count)}</p>` This way our custom hook acts as isolated model (data) without any view logic. All it needs to do is persist state, update & notify listeners (UI). That makes it more re-usable and clean. Just a thought :)

Comment: Great idea! We can surely do that. This was added just to showcase how we can use helper within the custom hook to seggregate any data manipulation from react component.

Comment: Great answer! Love the clear separation of concerns.

Comment: learning react after working in Angular for years and it is really frustrating to have all the rendering and component logic in one place and that too html(jsx) below a ton of business of logic.  This is exactly what i was looking for.  I think this should be default convention that every component should be have a hook for business logic keeping the UI component lean.

Comment: great example, I was using customHooks for different purposes but it's a helpful approach for separating logic.

Comment: it is error-prone, repetitive, and boring to define variables and set them again in return in the Hook especially when you have a lot of statuses, isn't there something better? like exposing every variable here? or use a class/object?

Answer (score 5):

A common approach that I use myself is to separate the business logic into its own file `myComponentHelper.js`

This will also make it easier to test the function because it will not be able to use and change the react state without having it passed in as arguments and returning the changes.

```
myComponent/
  myComponent.jsx
  myComponentHelper.js
  myComponentTest.js
```

```js
// myComponent.js

import { someFunc } from './myComponentHelper';

function MyComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');
    
    const x = someFunc(data);

    return ( 
        ...
    )
}
```

```js
// myComponentHelper.js

export const someFunc = (data) => {
    //do something.
    return something;
}
```

```js
// myComponentTest.js

import { someFunc } from './myComponentHelper';

test("someFunc - When data is this - Should return this", () => {
    const data = {...};
    const result = someFunc(data);
    expect(result).toEqual("correct business data");
});
```

Comment: Can you give a basic implementation?

Comment: Yes. Here is a basic implementation. https://codesandbox.io/embed/long-butterfly-1q2pw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FmyComponent%2FmyComponent.helper.js&theme=dark

Answer (score 2):

Separating business logic into other files can be done in various different ways.

1. Create a helperFile.js that has logic or basically the functions required by the corresponding file.
2. Creating Custom Hooks. More on that can be found [here in the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)
   or [in this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF2lQ_gZeA8&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwisvxhZ135pogtX7_Oe3Q3A&ab_channel=Codevolution)
   (refer the videos at the very end)
3. Global State mangement way - where [contextAPI](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) is  used to seperate out state and business logic